# Unable to set iPython to use 2.6.1 Python

Tags: python, ipython

I have installed the newest iPython in Mac. However, it uses the Python verion 2.5.1.

I installed the Python 2.6.1 by MacPython package at [here](http://www.python.org/download/).

**How can I make my iPython to use Python 2.6.1?**

I am not sure where the MacPython package exactly installed the newest Python.
The **newest Python should somehow put the PATH** so that iPyhon can use it.

**[edit]** after the first answer

I run the following command

```
$ln -s python python2.6
```

I cannot open python2.6 by

```
python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a python, python2.5 and python2.6, is that correct? If you wan't to use python2.6 system wide the symple solution would be to sym link (ln -s ..) python to python2.6 instead of python2.5

Comment: I run the following $ln -s python python2.6, but $ python does not open Python2.6.

Comment: you got it the the wrong way around you need to do $ln -s /full/path/to/python2.6 /full/path/to/python

/full/path/to needs to be replaced with the real path name for where the python2.6 is installed (by default /opt/local/bin/ if you installed it with macports)

Answer (score 4):

A good way to get it to work is [here.](http://www.jamesmurty.com/2009/06/05/ipython-with-python-2_6-osx-leopard/) I needed to restart my terminal before ipython pointed to python2.6. Note the latest ipython distribution is 0.10, not 0.9.

Comment: This answer is correct. The accepted answer is just a hack that doesn't address the problem.